# Dyamically table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a table like in the pictures in loops but I do not understand how to do it.

1. Create a JavaScript file and write the code for a function that draws the table.
2. Invoke the function when the visitor clicks on the original page.
3. Load the file at the end of the body in HTML.

Comment: This process typically involves directly setting the `innerHTML` property of an HTML object such as `body`.  The value you set is text, so you can easily build up the text of the required table.  Once the table is built, then set the appropriate object.  You might consider having a special `div` set aside to receive this table.  Also consider https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: @abiessu using the innerHTML method is not the best advice, javascript offers better.

Comment: @MisterJojo: that's cool, I can learn methods that are new to me.

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
function createTable( rowCount, columnCount )
  {
  let newTable = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table'))
  for(let r=0;r<rowCount;++r)  
    { 
    let newRow = newTable.insertRow()
    for(let c=0;c<columnCount;++c)
      { 
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = `${r}-${c}`
      }
    }
  }
```